# Derivative of hyperbolic tangent equation?

Tags: derivatives

Suppose I have the following hyperbolic tangent function:
$$\ f(x)=\frac{(1-e^{-2x})}{(1+e^{-2x})}$$

What will be the first derivative of this function?

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: that isn't an [equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation), since there's no equality. It's an [expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(mathematics)).

Comment: First of all, welcome to MSE. When posting a question, please also show attempts of solving it for yourself. Note that formally, we can only derive functions, not equations/expressions. Now have you tried the quotient rule for derivatives? ($(f/g)'=\frac {gf'-fg'}{g^2}$).

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Derivatives), but you could also derive it by hand as user robjohn does quite nicely. Wikipedia also mentions that the hyperbolic tangent is the solution to the system $$f' = 1-f^2$$ $$f(0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is a bit simpler to compute if we write it as
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}
&=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\\
&=1-\frac2{e^{2x}+1}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the derivative using the chain-rule gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac2{(e^{2x}+1)^2}2e^{2x}
&=\frac4{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}\\[6pt]
&=\mathrm{sech}^2(x)
\end{align}
$$